# how to send mail using CodeIgniter FrameWork php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to send mail using CodeIgniter Framework php?

and how much is it security?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

What sort of security are you thinking? Completely depends on your design.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the CI's community [receipt](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PHPMailer/) or check out the [guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)? And [here](http://www.lavluda.com/2008/05/19/phpmailer-for-codeigniter-ci/) is some description on how to install PHPMailer as CI's plugin.

You can also try standard php function [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Some day I've wrote a wrapper for this function that looks like this:

```
function sendmail($from, $to, $subject, $body, $isHtml = false, $encoding = 'windows-1251', $headers = -1) {
  GLOBAL $GLOBAL_SITE_DATA;
  $headersGlue = "\r\n";
  if (empty($encoding)) {
    $encoding = 'windows-1251';
  }
  $bracketPos = strpos($from,' 'Type here whatever you want!',
    'From' => $from,
    'Reply-To' => $replyTo,
    'Return-Path' => $returnPath,
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8bit',//'base64',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/'.($isHtml ? 'html':'plain').';  charset='.$encoding,
  );
  if (sizeof($headers) && $headers != -1) {
    foreach ($defaultHeaders as $headerKey => $header) {
      if (!isset($headers[$headerKey])) {
        $headers[$headerKey] = $header;
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($headers == -1) {
    $headers = $defaultHeaders;
  }

  $sHeaders = false; $sendWithHeaders = false;
  if (sizeof($headers) && $headers != -1) {
    array_walk($headers, create_function('&$v,$k', '$v = $k.": ".$v;'));
    $sHeaders = implode($headersGlue, $headers).$headersGlue;
    $sendWithHeaders = true;
  }
  return mail($to, '=?'.$encoding.'?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $body, ($sendWithHeaders ? $sHeaders : NULL));
}
```

You would want to change the default encoding (windows-1251 is for Cyrillic) and, probably, do some improvements.

Hope, it helps.